# Dart/WebStorm "Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription"

Tags: dart, webstorm

I am using WenStorm 2018.2.5 (registered), with the Dart plugin.

While editing a simple code, the editor shows me a message:

> Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription

[image]

I don't understand what this message means. I don't see what's wrong with the code. And, if I run the code inspection, the result is : "`No suspicious code found`".

Any idea ?

Note :

```
const int eventsCount = 5;
const int waitBetweenTwoEvents = 1;

typedef Streamer = Stream<int> Function();

...

Streamer streamCreator = () async* {
  for(int i=0; i<eventsCount; i++) {
    yield i;
    sleep(Duration(seconds: waitBetweenTwoEvents));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

This is shown when you have the linter rule enabled in `analysis_options.yaml`

```
linter:
  rules:
    - cancel_subscriptions
```

Either

- add `subscription.cancel()` somewhere in that class.
- remove the linter rule
- add a comment `// ignore: cancel_subscriptions` the line before or at the end of the line that shows the warning
- add a comment `// ignore_for_file: cancel_subscriptions` somewhere in the file

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure but I think that a stream subscription should be cancelled in order to allow the interpreter to make some clean up : "The stream may need to shut down the source of events and clean up after the subscription is canceled. Returns a future that is completed once the stream has finished its cleanup".

Comment: That's why the linter rule exists, but the linter rule doesn't understand your program. For example you might pass a reference to your subscription somewhere else to be cancelled there and the linter rule would not be able to follow that logic. You also might want to consume all events until the stream itself closes and don't intend to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you have a lint that requires you to cancel subscriptions.

In this case, I would just not create a subscription at all. Stream subscriptions are great when you want to control the stream by pausing or cancelling it early, or handling errors.
Here you just want to do something for each data event. That's what the [`Stream.forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Stream/forEach.html) method does. It even returns a future that is completed when the stream is done or has errored, so you don't need to do `subscription.asFuture`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, I am learning Dart and I try many things in order to test my comprehension. This code is just an experiment.