# warning with cancel_subscriptions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks, stream

i got this warning message  while i am using StreamSubscription .

Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription.

even though i do cancel it !!

[image]

i find similar question here
[Dart/WebStorm "Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265478/dart-webstorm-cancel-instances-of-dart-async-streamsubscription)

the answer was add a comment // ignore: cancel_subscriptions the line before or at the end of the line that shows the warning

but i don't think it is good idea to solve an issue by ignoring it special if it was sensitive or causing memory leak such in my case with `stream subscriptions`

Note i got this warning when i updated to latest `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`